# ERROR ITMS-90040 for submitting App UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend

Tags: ios, xcode, info.plist

I am trying to submit my app but i get this error when I try to submit it. I am looking over the build file and plist but can't figure out where I need to change this to fix it.

Thank you for any help with this.

```
ERROR ITMS-90040: "If the value of UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend is Yes, your app must not specify any values in the UIBackgroundModes key. If your app uses background services, the value of UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend must be No. For more information, refer to the Information Property List Key Reference."
 ERROR ITMS-90040: "If the value of UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend is Yes, your app must not specify any values in the UIBackgroundModes key. If your app uses background services, the value of UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend must be No. For more information, refer to the Information Property List Key Reference."
```

do I need to add another item in my plist file?
[image]

Comment: What is in your info.plist?  Do you use background modes?  The error message is pretty clear.

Comment: There I posted what my plist is like.

Comment: The only background I think I use is the push notficiaton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two values for *Required Background Modes* and you also have *Application does not run in background* set to **yes** - this is contradictory.  Either your app uses background modes or you don't want it to run in the background.

The typical value for *Application does not run in background* is **no**.  Setting it to **yes** gives the pre-iOS 3.2 behaviour where your app is terminated and removed from memory when the user presses the home button.

Even if you do not use background modes, you would typically set *Application does not run in background* to **no** so that your app doesn't need to completely restart when the user switches in and out of it.

Comment: That fixed it thank you. I didn't have any background running when I first started to build it, and now I do so you make a really good point about just setting it to no. Thank you once again